# NIntegrate and definite Integrate give different results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions, syntax

Suppose the function

```
f[x_,q_]=(15876 Exp[-0.527076 q^2] (x^2-2 x+2) SphericalBesselJ[1,5 q]^2 (q^2-8100 x^2))/(3425*Pi*q^5*x);
```

I need to perform the integration over `q` in the domain `{q,Max[90*x,2*10^-5],4.49/5}`, and then to plot the result for the `x` in ranges `{x,10^-8,4.49/(5*90)}`. The result must be real and positive.

I tried to plot both NIntegrate and Integrate:

```
g[x_] = Simplify[Integrate[f[x,q],{q,Max[90*x,2*10^-5],4.49/5}],Assumptions->{x>0, x<4.49/(5*90)}]
Plot[{g[x], 
  NIntegrate[
   f[x, q], {q, 
    Max[90*x, 2*10^-5], 4.49/5}]}, {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*90)}]
```

But it turns out that although the NIntegrate plots correct graphic, the Integrate returns complex function, whose real part doesn't coincide with the NIntegrate.

But if I try to slightly change the limits of the integration, the output is just the Integrate[...] itself!

What can be the reason for this? The initial function is smooth...

Comment: Might want to avoid inexact numbers in your `Integrate[]`.